# Windows XP Embedded PosReady 2009 support for TLS1.2

Tags: c#, security, ssl, tls1.2, posready

By default support for TLS1.2 is not enabled on Windows Embedded PosReady 2009.

However microsoft released KB4019276 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows) which adds this support.

Ive added the registry DWORD DisabledByDefault to the keys below as defined in the article.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server
```

Ive restarted the device after installing the KB and making the registry changes however its still not working for me. Below is the TLS1.2 code im using to test the changes.

The exception is

```
System.NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not supported.
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_SecurityProtocol(SecurityProtocolType value)
```

The code is compiled with .net 3.5 and 3.5 is the highest .net framework that this device will support.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to send TLS1.2 to google.com");
Console.ReadLine();

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;   // Sets TLS1.2. This will only work if the OS supports it. 

string url = "https://www.google.com";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";

var resp = req.GetResponse();
var outStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
string output = "";
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(outStream))
{
    output = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're trying to improve the security of a Windows XP machine? Here's the best way: get rid of it.

Comment: @mason Constructive feedback!! Easier said than done when your dealing with a huge number of devices installed at customer locations. Either way Microsoft is supporting PosReady until 2019 so we have another year left.

Comment: As this KB indicates, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the--net-framework, .NET 3.5.1 on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 are out of scope either. Thus, you really don't have much hope left.

Comment: Unfortunately, the update you reference [KB4019276](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows) only provides support for TLS 1.2 via Secure Channel (Schannel) and not via .NET Framework.  This *might* work if your app used Schannel.dll directly and not through .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is not supporting TLS1.2 for .NET versions less than 4.5 which cannot be installed on Embedded POS Ready 2009.  Very crappy solution they have provided!

Comment: unfortunately, I have to agree with you -- there is no solution for the combination of POSReady 2009 + .NET Framework + TLS 1.2.  If anyone can prove otherwise, we're all listening.

Answer (score 1):

I was in same situation. But I can use TLS1.2 on POSready2009 with .NET Framework 3.5 application now.

My machine is installed .NET Framework 4.0 also. Then all "Windows Update" is applied.
(If some updates are failed by Certificates Error, check [Update Root Certificates] in "Install or Remove Windows Components")

After installed KB4019276, I tried following changes for regstory:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AdvancedOptions\CRYPTO\TLS1.2" /v OSVersion /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Then you can find [Use TLS 1.2] in Internet Option's Advanced tab. Turn on [Use TLS 1.2] and turn off other [Use TLS/SSL x.x].

Answer (score 0):

Quinoshita is, in fact, correct. In XP SP3 POSReady2009, turning on TLS 1.2 in IE's options appears to enable .Net and older languages utilizing MSXML.XMLHTTP and MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP calls (for example) to work over TLS 1.2.  I'm running VB6 applications and was able to confirm TLS 1.2 connection using this bit of code:

```
   Sub Main()
         Dim objhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
         'or unrem this to test XMLHTTP
         'Dim objhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
         objhttp.open "GET", "https://howsmyssl.com/a/check", False
         'next line not required, just 
         objhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
         objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "text/html"
         objhttp.send
         Debug.Print objhttp.responseText
         Set objhttp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

As long as the response contains `"tls_version":"TLS 1.2"` then it's working correctly.

I was skeptical about the REG DELETE command in his post, but that did the trick for me and unveiled the TLS 1.2 option checkbox in Internet Options, in Control Panel. I had already made some of his other changes manually.